# Ubuntu 10.04+Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family: последствия?

Tags: видеокарта, ubuntu

Здравствуйте!

Имеется ноутбук FUJITSU AMILO Li3710 c видеоконтроллером Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family и ОС Ubuntu 10.04 на борту. Хотелось бы узнать мнение экспертов или опытных пользователей по поводу такого сочетания.

Как ОС использует ресурсы чипсета? Вопрос сводится к проблеме о периодических мерцаний монитора. А именно: мерцание в виде тонких цветовых полос. Отключил все эффекты, но безрезультатно: проблема не исчезает. На машине имеется вторая ОС Windows 7 Ultimate, там проблема не наблюдается, значит вариант повреждения железа отпадает (тем более, что ноутбук у меня не старый - всего год с лихвой).

Хотелось бы полностью перейти на свободный Ubuntu, но боюсь угробить машину. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уж 7 не угробила вашу технику, то 10.04 не может угробить однозначно, следуйте совету, приведённому выше. А вообще система сама должна была предложить установить проприетарный драйвер

попробуйте в терминале выполнить:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

Answer (score 1):

Полный формат спасет вас от лишней измены,устновите одну ОС и пользуйтесь себе на здоровье.Другой вопрос в вашем беспокойстве,относительно полос,возможно у вас не установленны проприетарные драйвера для видеокарты.Заходим в «Система» – «Администрирование» – «Драйверы устройстройв» Мой совет установить стандартный видеодрайвер,если такой имеется в списке.Проблема еще может заключаться в том,добавлен ли драйвер для вашей видеокарты в базу или нет.Драйвера [nvidia](http://www.nvidia.ru/object/linux_display_archive_ru.html) для linuxИмхо для вашего ноутбука только одну ОС,и только [crunchbang](http://crunchbanglinux.org/),я вам советую!

Пользватели виндовс хвастаются у кого комп круче,а линуксойды-у кого хуже:) (c)